# Stop and return error if row and column names don't match in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, runtime-error

I would like a function to stop and return an error message if the row names and column names of the two inputs do not match. Inputs may be either matrices or data.frames.

I have tried the following without success:

```
abun <- matrix(c(0.4,0,0.6,0.1,0.4,0.5), 
    nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, 
    dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), 
    c("A","B","C")))

x<-data.frame("Trait1" =c(1,1,0),"Trait2"=c(1,1,1),
        "Trait3" =c(1,1,0),"Trait4" =c(1,0,1))
rownames(x)<-c("A","B","D")                 


test<-function(abun,x){
if(colnames(abun) != rownames(x))stop("species names in abun and x do not match")
abun<-abun*2
abun        
}       

test(abun,x)
```

Any insights are most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `any` in the if statement.

```
test<-function(abun,x){
  if(any(colnames(abun) != rownames(x)))
    stop("species names in abun and x do not match")
  abun<-abun*2
  abun        
}
```

So that all results from the vector operation gets evaluated.

Comment: I see, thanks. So was it just checking the first instance with the script I had? 

Just to double check, with 'if' statements like this, is 'else' continue with the function assumed (i.e. you don't have to state explicitly to continue if the 'if' test is passed). Pretty sure it is but just wanted to check...

Comment: @Elizabeth yes that is correct. If the if statement evaluates to FALSE then the function continues.